# Applying data validation to specific columns in different sheets using openpyxl

Tags: excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to apply different data validation to different columns in different tabs using openpyxl.

My code works when I only specify one sheet, but it becomes mixed up when I define three sheets simultaneously.
chatgpt and google bard are giving me wrong answers only inventing code that does not compile, very frustrating. Can somebody help?

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.worksheet.datavalidation import DataValidation
from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter

# Anonymized state lists
state_list_1 = ["State1", "State2", "State3"]  # Anonymized list of financial institutions
state_list_2 = ["Yes", "No"]  # Anonymized list of yes/no options
state_list_3 = ["USD", "EUR", "CAD"]  # Anonymized list of currency codes

# Create a workbook
workbook = Workbook()
workbook.create_sheet('Tab 1')
workbook.create_sheet('Tab 2')
workbook.create_sheet('Tab 3')
workbook.create_sheet('List')
sheet_one = workbook['Tab 1']
sheet_two = workbook['Tab 2']
sheet_three = workbook['Tab 3']
sheet_four = workbook['List']

# Populate sheets with anonymized state lists
state_lists = [state_list_1, state_list_2, state_list_3]
for i, state_list in enumerate(state_lists, start=1):
    for idx, state in enumerate(state_list, start=1):
        sheet_four.cell(row=idx, column=i, value=state)

# Create data validations
data_1 = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='=List!$A:$A')
data_2 = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='=List!$B:$B')
data_3 = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='=List!$C:$C')

# Define columns to apply DataValidations
columns_to_validate = {
    'Tab 1': {5: data_2},
    'Tab 2': {8: data_2, 9: data_2, 14: data_3, 15: data_1, 23: data_2},
    'Tab 3': {6: data_3, 7: data_3, 8: data_1}
}

# Apply DataValidations to specified columns in respective sheets
for sheet_name, columns in columns_to_validate.items():
    sheet = workbook[sheet_name]
    for col_num, data in columns.items():
        column_letter = get_column_letter(col_num)
        sheet.add_data_validation(data)
        for row in range(3, sheet.max_row + 1):
            cell = f"{column_letter}{row}"
            data.add(sheet[cell])

# Saving the workbook
workbook.save('mwe.xlsx')
```

Comment: You have to be more specific - "mixed up" doesn't say much... Describe what went wrong.

Comment: The code sample creates new workbook with four additional sheets and no data entered into the sheets other than the last sheet called 'List'. So sheets 'Tab1', 'Tab2' and 'Tab3' are empty sheets. (Comment continues in next comment).

Comment: (Comment continued from previous) When adding the data validation *# Apply DataValidations to specified...* the loop uses the dictionary 'columns_to_validate' which only contains the empty sheets 'Tab(1 - 3). At the line `for row in range(3, sheet.max_row + 1):`, given  the sheets have no data and therefore no rows are used, this means the loop will never be executed, effectively being `range(3, 2)` and therefore `data.add(sheet[cell])` never gets executed resulting in a corrupted workbook. Are those sheets 'Tab(1 - 3)' supposed to be populated somewhere or why start at row 3?

Comment: @kb2136 by mixed up I meant, I want specific columns in sheet 1-2-3 to have specific data validation lists A-B-C. Instead, I got all tabs with all columns specified for sheets 1-2-3 with all data validation lists.

Comment: @moken sorry I was a bit lazy on building my MWE, you're right, my actual file is filled with data for Tabs 1-2-3

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments. In the end I solved my problem by defining different DataValidation objects for each sheet (the code could be shorter by using a double loop function, but it works).

```
`data_1_sheet_one = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='=List!$A:$A')
data_2_sheet_one = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='=List!$B:$B')
data_3_sheet_one = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='=List!$C:$C')
data_1_sheet_two = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='=List!$A:$A')
data_2_sheet_two = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='=List!$B:$B')
data_3_sheet_two = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='=List!$C:$C')
data_1_sheet_three = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='=List!$A:$A')
data_2_sheet_three = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='=List!$B:$B')
data_3_sheet_three = DataValidation(type="list", formula1='=List!$C:$C')

# Apply data validation to entire columns in different sheets
for row in range(1, 100): 
    cell = f"E{row}"
    data_2_sheet_one.add(sheet_one[cell])

sheet_one.add_data_validation(data_2_sheet_one)

for row in range(1, 100): 
    cell = f"O{row}"
    data_1_sheet_two.add(sheet_two[cell])

for row in range(1, 100): 
    cell = f"H{row}"
    data_2_sheet_two.add(sheet_two[cell])

for row in range(1, 100): 
    cell = f"I{row}"
    data_2_sheet_two.add(sheet_two[cell])

for row in range(1, 100): 
    cell = f"H{row}"
    data_2_sheet_two.add(sheet_two[cell])

for row in range(1, 100): 
    cell = f"N{row}"
    data_3_sheet_two.add(sheet_two[cell])

for row in range(1, 100): 
    cell = f"W{row}"
    data_2_sheet_two.add(sheet_two[cell])

sheet_two.add_data_validation(data_1_sheet_two)
sheet_two.add_data_validation(data_2_sheet_two)
sheet_two.add_data_validation(data_3_sheet_two)

for row in range(1, 100): 
    cell = f"F{row}"
    data_3_sheet_three.add(sheet_three[cell])

for row in range(1, 100): 
    cell = f"G{row}"
    data_3_sheet_three.add(sheet_three[cell])

for row in range(1, 100): 
    cell = f"H{row}"
    data_1_sheet_three.add(sheet_three[cell])

sheet_three.add_data_validation(data_1_sheet_three)
sheet_three.add_data_validation(data_2_sheet_three)
sheet_three.add_data_validation(data_3_sheet_three)`
```